# sharing git repository on network drive

Tags: git

I am using github for windows, and I am trying to follow this tutorial: 
http://www.gitguys.com/topics/creating-a-shared-repository-users-sharing-the-repository/
There is one difference though, I am trying to share an existing local repository.  I created a blank repository on the network drive with git init --bare.  Then I went into my local repository and set the origin url to the remote repository I just created.  Then I did git push origin master git push origin otherBranch etc.  All seemed to go well.  But when I try to clone that remote repository into another directory for testing, it seems to bring down the working directory, but not the commit history or other branches etc.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you `cd` into the network drive in a command window and type `git log`, what do you get? How about `git branch`? In the cloned working directory, can you see the `.git` directory if you look for hidden files?

Comment: Wow I am an idiot.  I didn't realize when you cloned a repository, it automatically put it into a subdirectory, so I was looking for it in the directory where I was.  oh my.

Comment: OK. Make that an answer and mark it accepted, so this question doesn't appear as "unanswered" in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was user error on my part, I didn't realize when you cloned a git repository it automatically created a subdirectory and so I was looking in the same directory I was when I cloned.  Oops.